# Change any number of delimiters in found pattern with sed

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I want to change every `.` to  `@.@`  with sed, but only if the `.` is enclosed with numbers.
For example:

```
This sentence ends with a dot. 1.2.3
Dot. 1.2.3.4.5 Dot.
```

The goal:

```
This sentence ends with a dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3
Dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3 @.@ 4 @.@ 5 Dot.
```

The pattern could contain **any number** of integers.

I tried:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1 @\.@ \2/g'
```

but it only works for the first two number in the pattern.

Comment: IMHO, tags of perl, regex, awk were added by OP in original question itself, along with it answers are also given as per it(it includes all mentioned tags answers here), thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the repeated pattern (number-dot-number-dot-number...) that substitution doesn't work because the number following the dot is
"consumed" and so the engine moved along the string, so the next character it sees is a dot, not the needed num-dot-num  pattern.

One solution is to use [lookarounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind),<sup>†</sup> which are "zero-width" assertions, so with which the engine doesn't consume the match and doesn't move along, but it merely "looks" from its "spot" between characters to assert that the pattern (ahead or behind) matches, so to say

```
s/ (?<=[0-9]) \. (?=[0-9]) / @.@ /gx;
```

For a testable example (in Perl, as tagged)

```
perl -wE'$_=q(Dot. 1.2.3.4.5 Dot.); say; s/(?<=[0-9])\.(?=[0-9])/ @.@ /g; say'
```

which prints

```
Dot. 1.2.3.4.5 Dot.
Dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3 @.@ 4 @.@ 5 Dot.
```

But the lookbehind won't work with a "*number*" that consists of more than one digit, since then we'd need `[0-9]+` which has variable and unlimited length, whiat lookbehinds can't (yet) do.

If it is indeed possible to have multi-digit numbers in your case, then the number before the `.` need be captured -- this still works with the number *before* the dot -- and then put back

```
s/([0-9]+)\.(?=[0-9])/$1 @.@ /g;
```

This can be done anyway, of course, even if it's all always single digits;  i used lookbehind originally only for the symmetry with the other side (needing a lookahead)

---

<sup>†</sup>  In a tool that supports them, which in my understanding `sed` isn't.  (Thanks to comments by `potong` and `Ed Morton` for informing of that) I still offer this solution since Perl is one of the tagged languages.

Comment: It should be noted that these solutions will not work with the majority of sed versions.

Comment: @potong  Thanks for that comment, I edited the answer to state it explicitly.  I got a bit tired of the guessing game of whether they want this language or that, between what is mentioned in text/title and what is tagged.  So I take it that if it's in the tag it's an equal target. (This can be debated of course.)  I do appreciate an actual straigth-up `sed` answer, as by tshiono and Ed (upvoted), but I take other tagged languages as valid as well.  (I understand that you didn't challenge that, just saying...)

Answer (score 6):

As for the 1st line, the regex matches `1.2` for the 1st trial.
The next pattern match starts with the character `.` just after the
previous match then it fails.
With `sed` please try:

```
sed -E '
:l
s/([[:digit:]])\.([[:digit:]])/\1 @.@ \2/
t l
' file
```

which iterates the pattern match from the start of the string.

As you are adding `perl` in the tag, here is an alternative with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)/ @.@ /g' file
```

Comment: An alternative `sed -E 's/([0-9])\.([0-9])/\1 @.@ \2/g;s//\1 @.@ \2/g' file` since those substitutions not matched in a first pass will be in the second.

Comment: You should mention that will only work in a sed that has a `-E` argument, e.g. GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed, but idk if the script itself would would work in a non-GNU sed since anything more than s/old/new is usually GNU-specific.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='([0-9]+.)+[0-9]+' '{gsub(/\./," @.@ ",RT);ORS=RT;print}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making record separator as digits(one or more occurrences) with dot(.)'s one or more occurrences followed with 1 or more digits occurrences. Then substituting dot coming at last with `@.@` as per OP's request, resetting ORS and printing that line then. To get more info on `awk` you could check `man awk` page too.

Answer (score 3):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1 @.@ \2/g; s/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1 @.@ \2/g' file
This sentence ends with a dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3
Dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3 @.@ 4 @.@ 5 Dot.
```

You need 2 passes of the input because given input of `1.2.3` only `1.2` will be matched by the first pass of `[0-9]\.[0-9]`, the `2.3` won't be recognized in that pass because the `2` was already consumed by the first match so all that's left of the input in that first pass is `.3`, you need the 2nd pass (now against `1 @.@ 2.3`) to match `2.3`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a POSIX awk solution:

```sh
awk '{while (match($0, /[0-9]\.[0-9]/))
   $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART) " @.@ " substr($0, RSTART+2)} 1' file

This sentence ends with a dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3
Dot. 1 @.@ 2 @.@ 3 @.@ 4 @.@ 5 Dot.
```